# Запись в файл, не изменяя тип данных, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в python сохранить в файл переменную с типом dlib.array, не преобразуя в строку?

Comment: Скажите, а почему вам важно не преобразовывать их в строку?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно потом найти Евклидово расстояние между дескрипторами, а оно требует того, чтобы в файле были именно векторы. Пытался найти документацию непосредственно от создателей, но так и не нарыл способа преобразования строки в dlib.array

Comment: Файл — это по определению последовательность байтов, а последовательность байтов (если их считать символами) — это по определению строка. Так что ответ — никак, это невозможно

Comment: Но что-то мне подсказывает, что вам вполне подойдёт преобразование в строку и обратно с помощью какого-нибудь pickle (если он применим к dlib.array)

Comment: Тогда возможно ли преобразовать непосредственно сам текстовый файл в нужный формат для вычисления Евклидового расстояния, если да, то как?

Comment: @АлександрКуликов "Евклидово расстояние" в данном случае - расстояние между точками?

Comment: Оно самое, и точек там огромное количество

Comment: @АлександрКуликов Ну запишется оно человекочитаемой строкой - нет проблем обратно считать и преобразовать в числа. Непонятна суть проблемы.

Comment: абстракция файла это последовательность байт, то есть "запись в файл" и "не преобразуя в строку" не совместимы.  В зависимости от того что из себя dlib.array тип представляет могут быть несколько способов записать в файл и прочитать обратно объекты этого типа. К примеру, `numpy.array` имеет save() метод, а `array.array` — `tofile()`.

Comment: Было бы хорошо, но оно не хочет вычисляться, если данные представляют из себя строку. Мне выкидывает TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1279') dtype('<U1279') dtype('<U1279')

Comment: @АлександрКуликов , я не эксперт, но рекомендовал бы вам посмотреть в сторону сериализации

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо, вопрос решен. Все прекрасно работает, если работать с векторами через NumPy:

```
np.save("test.npy", face_descriptor1)
np.save("test1.npy", face_descriptor2)
Сохранить векторы


v1 = np.load("test.npy")
v2 = np.load("test1.npy")
Загрузить векторы

dist = distance.euclidean(v1, v2)
Найти Евклидово расстояние
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя [np.savez_compressed()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) можно сохранить несколько объектов в один сжатый файл.

Пример:

```
In [14]: import dlib

In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: a = dlib.array([1,2,3,4])

In [17]: b = dlib.array([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4])
```

Сериализация:

```
In [18]: np.savez_compressed(r'c:/temp/f.npz', a=a, b=b)
```

Десериализация:

```
In [19]: npzfiles = np.load(r'c:/temp/f.npz')

In [20]: npzfiles.files
Out[20]: ['a', 'b']

In [21]: a1 = npzfiles['a']

In [22]: b1 = npzfiles['b']
```

Проверка:

```
In [23]: a1 == a
Out[23]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [24]: (b1 == b).all()
Out[24]: True
```